# Intercepting Polymer events

Tags: javascript, polymer

To intercept browser event one can write something like  this:

```
<input type="radio" onChange="alert('on change!')">
```

What would be the easiest way to intercept POLYMER component event?
Like this one:

```
 <paper-radio-button   on-iron-change="alert('on-iron-change!!')" />
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<paper-radio-button   on-iron-change="someFunctionOnTheCustomElement" />
```

otherwise you can imperatively add an event listener

```
document.querySelector('paper-radio-button')
    .addEventListener('iron-change', (e) { alert('on-iron-change'); }
```